# alias you requested not exist: error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, alias

This is crazy, but I have a jquery plugin (http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall) that displays the FB Wall on my website.  It was working like a charm 3 days ago and then boom I start getting this error: "The alias you requested does not exist: 274371937343"

The FB page is still up and running...  I see it: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Oregon-Association-of-Synchronized-Swimming/274371937343?ref=ts

Even when I try and fetch the object at  https://graph.facebook.com/274371937343 it returns false.

It was working a couple of days ago.  I'm pulling my hair out!  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  Julia

Answer (score 2):

Facebook just switched their graph api to now require an access token for this request.  So you will need to get and send over an access_token parameter on the graph api call.  The plugin you are using may not be updated yet to reflect that.

The reference post for this is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/). Pretty lame they give you less than a weeks notice, especially in a post titled "Operation Developer Love".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that geographic filtering was turned on for our Facebook page. Not sure if that helps but turning it off fixed it for me. (Age filtering would do the same thing)